# Parse - About sessionToken and be logged in to few devices at the same time from the same user

Tags: javascript, android, web, parse-platform

There is a way to login to the same user from different devices?
I have an `Android app` and web app and I want to be able to be logged in for both apps at the same time.
I'm getting `error 209 "invalid session token"` when logged in at the second app(`web or android`).
I'll glad to get some information about that error and how can i solve my problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i solved the problem by checking for Parse errors using:

```
function handleParseError(err) {
  switch (err.code) {
    case Parse.Error.INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN:
      var c = Parse.User.current();
      var q = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
      var u = c.get("username");
      var p;
      q.equalTo("username", u);
        q.first().then(function(r) {
          p = r.get("codeEntry");
      });

      Parse.User.logOut();

      Parse.Cloud.run("logIn", {"username": u, "codeEntry": p});
      break;
  }
}
```

explain - in case the session token is invalid i'm getting the `username` and the `codeEntry`(this app based on AnyPhone). then i'm using `Parse.User.logOut()` to logout the user and then i'm using `Parse.Cloud.run()` to run a Cloud Code function called `logIn`:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("logIn", function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var phoneNumber = req.params.phoneNumber;
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');

   if (phoneNumber && req.params.codeEntry) {
       Parse.User.logIn(phoneNumber, req.params.codeEntry).then(function (user) {
           res.success(user.getSessionToken());
        }, function (err) {
           res.error(err);
       });
    } else {
      res.error('Invalid parameters.');
    }
});
```

and that's it, everything works just fine!